# $(this).data('dynamic_id') is undefined except in alert

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, this, custom-data-attribute

How do I use the data-attribute to pass a dynamically generated id from a rails app to jQuery?  When I try, the value returns undefined unless I just send it to an alert box.

This code (which uses the debug link as a hack):

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
    $('.debug_link_id').click ->
        alert $(this).data('dynamic_id)
```

Shows the dynamic_id in the alert box.

However, using the same selector, this code:

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
    jqVar = $(this).data('dynamic_id')
    $('.debug_link_id').click ->
        alert jqVar
```

Shows "undefined" in the alert box. 
[using .attr('data-dynamic_id') gives the same results]

Kindly tell me:

1. Why the first code works and the second doesn't
2. If there is a better strategy for pulling dynamic id's into jQuery

Comment: What triggers `page:change` event? What is `$(this)` within `page:change` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to set `this` to `"#debug_link_id"` within handler.

```
  $(document).on "page:change", "#debug_link_id", ->
```

Comment: What is purpose of creating a `click` handler within another event handler?

Comment: I'm using this to figure out what is happening with jQuery.

Comment: @MichaelvanHolst Did you read linked page above? Have you checked what `$(this)` is at `jqVar = $(this).data('dynamic_id')`?

Comment: According to the alert $(this) = [object Object]

Comment: @MichaelvanHolst What is result of `console.log(this)`?

Comment: At `jqVar = $(this).data('dynamic_id')`  `jqVar` would be getter for `.data('dynamic_id')` at that element, not selector `$(this)`

Comment: @MichaelvanHolst What is expected result of `jqVar = $(this).data('dynamic_id')` ?

Comment: Yes this worked fine thank you. Although I am not sure  how to check the values you have asked for. The event delegation did allow me to capture the id successfully.  `$('#parent').on 'click', 'a', (event) -> jqVar = $(this).data('dynamic_id')`

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are referring the `this` in the wrong place..

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
    $('#debug_link_id').click ->
        alert $(this).data('dynamic_id)// <-- That "this" is referring a object with id debug_link_id

$(document).on "page:change", ->
    jqVar = $(this).data('dynamic_id') //<-- That "this" is referring a object that I don't know where this is come from...
    $('#link_id').click ->
        alert jqVar
```

Comment: Sorry, In both instances I am clicking the debug link. I missed that in editing my question.

Comment: when you put `$(this)` inside some events handlers in jquery, you are meaning that you want to use the current object of your function.